# Asymptotic form of the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} dx ~ \sqrt{x^2 + wx} ~ e^{-ixs}$ for $s \to \infty$

Tags: integration, asymptotics, improper-integrals

I would like to find an asymptotic form of the following integral when $s \to \infty$ ($s$ and $w$ are positive)

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} dx ~ \sqrt{x^2 + wx} ~ e^{-ixs}
\end{equation}

I have tried a change of variable first $xs = y$ to get

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dy}{s}~ \sqrt{\frac{y^2}{s^2} + \frac{wy}{s}} e^{-iy}
\end{equation}
I suspect also that the main contribution will come from around $y=0$, and I know that the rapid oscillations of the integrand will cancel most of the integral outside that region, so I could perform the integral only up to $L$ instead of $\infty$ (although I am not sure what $L$ should be chosen). This, I think, would lead to the asymptotics (first order is enough) for the integral being

$$
\sqrt{w/s} \int_0^L dy ~ \sqrt{y} e^{-iy}
$$
Is this correct and or can be improved?

Comment: Did you convince yourself that the integral converges at all?

Comment: It is convergent. That integral appears in a standard physics calculation (although the book I follow does not say how it is done)

Comment: see my answer below and convince yourself that the integral does in fact not converge (as stated). In order that the integral converges, you need to have $\text{Im}\,s<0$.

Comment: Indeed, I will go through it carefully. Thanks!

Comment: *That integral appears in a standard physics calculation (although the book I follow does not say how it is done)* - It is expressible in terms of the [Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function). Just complete the square inside the radical and use an appropriate hyperbolic substitution, then recognize the expression of the afore-mentioned function in the new integral.

Comment: To be precise, the integral *does not converge*. That is, $$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_0^\lambda\sqrt{x^2+wx}\,e^{-ixs}\,\mathrm{d}x$$ does not exist. It oscillates with greater and greater amplitude as $\lambda\to\infty$. We have to do some heavy regularization (Fabian does it by requiring $\mathrm{Im}(s)\lt0$) to get a value for the integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that in order for the integral to make sense, we should consider $s$ to be complex with $\text{Im}\,s <0$. In fact, Fourier (or Laplace) transforms make in general the most sense in the context of complex calculus.

So let me rephrase your question:

- find the asymptotic behavior of $$\begin{equation}
  I(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \!dx \, \sqrt{x^2 + wx} \, e^{-ixs}
  \end{equation}$$ for $|s| \to \infty$ and the wedge in the complex plane for which this result applies (see [Stokes phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_phenomenon))

The asymptotic analysis can be performed by the method of steepest decent. In fact we can deform the integration over $x\in[0,\infty)$ into the lower half-plane of the complex $x$ plane. In particular, we have with $y=i x$
$$I(s) = -i \int_{0}^{\infty} \!dy \, \sqrt{-y^2- i w y} \, e^{-s y} .$$
For $s\to\infty$, the integral is dominated for $y$ close to 0. We can thus expand the square root and obtain
$$I(s) \sim -i \sqrt{-i w} \int_0^\infty \!dy \, \Bigl[y^{1/2}  + O(y^{3/2}) \Bigr] e^{-s y}
\sim - \tfrac12 \pi^{1/2} e^{i\pi/4} w^{1/2}  s^{-3/2} \tag{1}$$
with the next term proportional to $s^{-5/2}$. As explained above the result is valid for $\text{Im}\,s<0$.

Comment: @glance: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: another thing: don't we also need to assume $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$ for the rotated integral (your second formula) to be convergent? Also, I don't understand the minus sign in the last term of **(1)**. Don't you have $$-i\sqrt{-iw}=\sqrt{iw}=e^{i\pi/4}w^{1/2} ?$$

Comment: @glance: yes you need Re$(s)>0$ in the rotated integral. However, afterwards to can analytically continue the result to understand that it coincides with the original integral whenever the latter converges.

Comment: Regarding the sign: as you most probably well know the sign of the sqrt-operation is ambiguous as the function is multivalued in a complex setting. We need to take the branch  which is analytically connected to $\sqrt{x^2 + wx}>0$ in the original integral when rotating the contour to the lower half plane.

Comment: you are right about the sign, sorry: you have to consider $\sqrt{-i} = e^{-i\pi/4}= -i e^{i\pi/4}$ which gives the correct result. One last thing, regarding the issue of the requirement of $\operatorname{Re}(s) >0$ in your second equation: so you are saying that we can just consider the derivation and the obtained result as valid only for $\operatorname{Re}(s) >0$, and at the end consider the final result **(1)** to be extendible by analytic continuation to the other regions of the complex plane? But isn't this non-trivial because of the very Stokes phenomenon you quoted?

Answer (score 3):

In the quadrant $[0,R]\cup Re^{-i\pi[0,1/2]}\cup[-iR,0]$ there are no singularities, so we can adjust the contour anywhere in that quadrant.

Furthermore, the part of the integral past any fixed $x$ decays exponentially in $s$, so we only need pay attention to the part near $0$:
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{t\to0^-}\int_0^\infty\sqrt{x^2+wx}\,e^{-ix(s+it)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\int_0^\infty\sqrt{x^2+iwx}\,e^{-xs}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{w}\int_0^\infty\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-ix/w}\,e^{-xs}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}w^2\int_0^\infty\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1-ix}\,e^{-xsw}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\sim-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}w^2\int_0^\infty\sqrt{x}{\small\left(1+\frac{\frac12}1(-ix)+\frac{\frac12(-\frac12)}{1\cdot2}(-ix)^2+\frac{\frac12(-\frac12)(-\frac32)}{1\cdot2\cdot3}(-ix)^3+\dots\right)}\,e^{-xsw}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}w^2{\small\left(\frac{\sqrt\pi}2(sw)^{-3/2}-\frac i2\frac{3\sqrt\pi}4(sw)^{-5/2}+\frac18\frac{15\sqrt\pi}8(sw)^{-7/2}+\frac i{16}\frac{105\sqrt\pi}{16}(sw)^{-9/2}+\dots\right)}\\
&=-\frac{1+i}{2\sqrt2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi w}{s^3}}{\small\left(1-i\frac3{4sw}+\frac{15}{32(sw)^2}+i\frac{105}{128(sw)^3}+\dots\right)}\\
\end{align}
$$
The first term agrees with Fabian's formula.

Comment: @glance: I guess you are still wondering about the substitution.  The substitution from the first line to the second is $x\mapsto-ix$. Then $\sqrt{x^2+wx}\,\mathrm{d}x\mapsto-\sqrt{x^2+iwx}\,\mathrm{d}x$